# Making app appear in google chrome "share list option"?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, android-intent, xamarin.forms

I am trying to make my app appear on the Google's share list option. There is already a lot of created posts about listing app in share list option but I can't find an answer. As from my understanding, Google will use a different intent and only list apps with that specific intent?

That is what I am trying to do.

The code I added is this

```
  <activity android:name=".ui.MyActivity" >
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
</intent-filter>
```

But the app is not appearing in Google's share list option. Not even when I download an image and try to share it through the library. The app is just not showing up.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gc6B3.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in addition to add ability to get content from other apps you need to add this  :

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Comment: Hey, I added it under my activity tag along with the rest of the code in my question post. When i try to share an image in google chrome, the app is still not showing up in the option list.

Comment: can you add                 `<data android:mimeType="*/*" />`
 to you code !

Comment: It is already in there? check line 28.  https://gyazo.com/bc714b320e33b897eb340d4429cc8ff9

Comment: Oh! the problem was that the activity tag was outside the application tag!. Appriciate your help. Good answer, thank you!

Comment: Got any recommendations on how i would be able to handle this share event from this? the .cs code

Answer (score 0):

i didn't test it but in the MainActivity can you add this before class declaration

```
 [IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionSend }, Categories = new[] {
        Android.Content.Intent.CategoryDefault,
        Android.Content.Intent.CategoryBrowsable
    }, DataMimeType = "text/plain")]
```

and in the OnCreate method add

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Intent.GetStringExtra(Intent.ExtraText)))
        {
            string subject = Intent.GetStringExtra(Intent.ExtraSubject) ?? "subject not available";
            Toast.MakeText(this, subject, ToastLength.Long).Show();
        }
```

this for text and test purpose you can debug to verify that the app reach this code then you could change it with you needs